# Writing a generic function for minimum element in arrays of integers and characters(strings) in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I am trying to write a generic function to obtain the minimum element in an array of integers or strings. I am using memory functions to do so. The following is the code which I wrote:

**Edit: Modified code** - I changed int size from int size_t

```
/* Write a function that returns minimum values of an array of integers or strings */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void returnMinAddress(void *a, void *b, int arr_size, int size) {
  b = a;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    if (memcmp(b, a+((i)*size), size) < 0) {
      memmove(b, a+((i)*size), size);
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  void *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
  /* For an array of type integer */
  int a[8] = {3, 2, 1, -4, 6, 9, 8, -1};
  returnMinAddress(a, b, 8, sizeof(int));
  printf("The result is : %d\n", *(int *)b);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

After spending good amount of time, I fail to understand why do **I keep getting my answer as 0**.. The following is the screenshot of the output. What am I missing here?

**Original Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void returnMinAddress(void *a, void *b, int arr_size, int size_t) {
  b = a;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    if (memcmp(b, a+((i)*size_t), size_t) < 0) {
      memmove(b, a+((i)*size_t), size_t);
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  void *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
  /* For an array of type integer */
  int a[8] = {3, 2, 1, -4, 6, 9, 8, -1};
  returnMinAddress(a, b, 8, sizeof(int));
  printf("The result is : %d\n", *(int *)b);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: What is this: `a+((i)*size_t)`??? Does it even compile? Are you aware `size_t` is a type name?

Comment: After doing `b = a;`, your `memmove()` is overwriting the array, not writing into the caller's `b` variable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I suspect he's using a compiler that allows `void*` arithmetic as an extension, and treats it like `char*`.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't do this with structs unless you're 100% sure you know what you're doing. Padding, magic bytes, etc, will cause "identical" structs to fail `memcmp()` operations erroneously.

Comment: @EOF I just tried it on OS X, I got no error. Are variables and typedefs separate namespaces?

Comment: More generally, `memcmp()` cannot be relied upon to produce results equivalent to the regular comparison operators applied to the declared type of the pointed-to objects, except where the objects being compared are individual `unsigned char`s.

Comment: When I add `-pedantic`, I get warnings about using the GNU extension of pointer arithmetic on `void*`. Still no complaints about using `size_t` as a variable.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right. I didn't know this kind of insanity doesn't warrant a warning on modern compilers.

Comment: @EOF, I am fairly confident that it's a scoping issue.  The OP's `size_t` is scoped to the declared function; there, it can shadow the file-scope type definition for the same identifier.  But it's still poor form on multiple grounds.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, that's what my testing suggests as well. Weirdly, `-Wshadow` doesn't help either.

Comment: @EOF Even more insanity, you can declare it: `size_t size_t`.

Comment: @EOF An old PL/I joke is that it doesn't have reserved words, so you can write `for for from from to to do ...`

Comment: @EOF Where does the Standard exactly say that you can not (or it is prohibided) name your variable with a name owned by a type name (like a typedef in this case)?

Comment: @Olaf I use `GCC-6` with this FLAGS =>> `-Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -O0 -g`. It does not on my Linux mint. SO if I do this `int size_t = 5;` I get: `error: unused variable ‘size_t’`

Comment: If that was a good idea, don't you think the standard library would already provide this? Your code relies on undefined behaviour behaving defined (which is does not by definition) and implementation defined behaviour. Let apart the performance issue. Better write individual functions and use the `_Generic` operator.

Comment: @Barmar If you declare `int size_t = 5;` as Global, the Compiler will see it: `error: ‘size_t’ redeclared as different kind of symbol` Probably this is what OLAF was telling, I guess.

Comment: @Michi: Hmm, just tried myself with `-Wshadow` explictily (I never tried this for types and variables). I stand corrected, that's strange indeed. You can even declare `size_t size_t` without warning.

Comment: @Olaf *Which* `gcc` gave a warning for `int size_t`? I can't get *any* of the compilers on `gcc.godbolt.org` to give a warning even with `-Wshadow`.

Comment: @EOF: See above. It appears I was too quickly assuming the behaviour for variables also works for types vs. variables.

Comment: @EOF Only if you declare it as Global. See my Above comment

Comment: @Michi: I assumed gcc would report shadowing for names in general. I only saw this once for two variables (I don't write such code). As there are no custom namespaces in C, I thought it was safe to assume. Apparently it was not :-/

Comment: @spunkpike  I am sure your answer should not be down-voted because you tried to write the function yourself and the idea deserves to be considered.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank You :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your generic function is invalid.

First of all though `size_t` is not a keyword nevertheless it is a type specifier. So it is a bad idea to use this word as an identifier.

This statement

```
b = a;
```

should be replaced with

```
memmove( b, a, size_t );
```

Secondly according to the C Stndard you may not apply the pointer arithmetic to pointers of type `void *` because the type `void` is an incomplete type. So you should write for example

```
( char * )a + i * size_t
```

instead of

```
a+((i)*size_t)
```

As the function searches the minimum then the condition in this statement

```
if (memcmp(b, a+((i)*size_t), size_t) < 0) {
```

should be written like

```
if ( memcmp( ( char * )a + i * size_t, b, size_t ) < 0)
```

Taking all this into account the function could look like

```
void returnMinAddress( void *a, void *b, size_t n, size_t m) 
{
    memmove(b, a, m);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if ( memcmp( ( char * )a + i * m, b, m ) < 0 ) 
        {
            memmove(b, ( char * )a + i * m, m );
        }
    }
}
```

However there is one more problem that the function can not resolve. Negative integers considered like a sequence of raw bytes can be greater than positive numbers. So if you will try the function shown above for your array

```
int a[8] = { 3, 2, 1, -4, 6, 9, 8, -1 };
```

you will get that the minimum is equal to `1`  while in realty it is equal to `-4`.

One of approaches to write such a generic function is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void * returnMinAddress( const void *a, size_t n, size_t m, int cmp( const void *, const void *) ) 
{
    const void *min = a;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if ( cmp( ( const char * )a + i * m, min ) < 0 ) 
        {
            min = (const char *)a + i * m;
        }
    }

    return (void *)min;
}

int cmp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    int a = *(const int *)p1;
    int b = *(const int *)p2;

    return (b < a) - (a < b);
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[8] = { 3, 2, 1, -4, 6, 9, 8, -1 };

    int *b = returnMinAddress(a, 8, sizeof(int), cmp_int);
    printf("The result is : %d\n", *b);
}
```

The program output is

```
The result is : -4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I wanted to write a generic function, then how should I proceed with it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41683546/2410359) well covered the troubles in OP's code.

An alternative to the providing 4 arguments to a *generic* function that need to match type and functionality, is to use `_Generic`.  Available since C11.  [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

```
// needs 4 arguments.  
// returnMinAddress(a, b, 8, sizeof(int));
// printf("The result is : %d\n", *(int *)b);
```

`_Generic` allows code to use the function that matches the needed type.
Only 2 arguments needed: pointer to first element and element count.

```
int *min_address_int(int *a, size_t count) {
  if (count == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int *min = a;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if (a[i] < *min) {
      min = &a[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
}

char *min_address_char(char *a, size_t count) {
  if (count == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char *min = a;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if (a[i] < *min) {
      min = &a[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
}

#define min_address(a, sz) (_Generic((a)+0, \
  char *: min_address_char((a)+0, (sz)), \
  int * : min_address_int ((a)+0, (sz)) \
  ))

int main(void) {
  int i[] = {3, 2, 1, -4, 6, 9, 8, -1};
  printf("Min int %d\n", *min_address(i, sizeof i/sizeof i[0]));

  char c[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'};
  printf("Min char %c\n", *min_address(c, sizeof c/sizeof c[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Min int -4
Min char !
```

Comment: It is a rare case when the generic selection is mentioned.:)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this line:

```
b = a;
```

After doing this, whenever the loop does:

```
memmove(b, a+((i)*size_t), size_t);
```

it's overwriting the first element of the input array, not copying into the caller's `b` variable. The simplest fix is to replace that with:

```
memmove(b, a, size_t);
```

But instead, I suggest using a pointer variable to point to the current minimum element. At the end of the loop, copy from this pointer to the caller's memory.

```
void returnMinAddress(void *a, void *b, int arr_size, int size_t) {
  void *min = a;
  for (int i = 1; i < arr_size; i++) { // start from 1 because min points to element 0
    if (memcmp(min, a+((i)*size_t), size_t) < 0) {
      min = a+((i)*size_t);
    }
  }
  memmove(b, min, size_t);
}
```

Also, the use of arithmetic on `void*` pointers is a GNU extension. You should cast them to `char*` to conform to standard C. And using the standard typedef `size_t` as a variable is poor style.

Comment: I get an answer as -1 and not -4 after trying your solution.. Could you also please explain why is that?

Comment: Two problems: You have the arguments to `memcmp()` backwards, and the problem described in the last paragraph of @VladfromMoscow's answer